# Update if exists, otherwise insert (without unique keys)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table that is created like this:

```
 'CREATE TABLE `boss_kills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `characterid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

**Goal**: I'm trying to create a system where a player kills a boss in the game and it records the boss's ID and the player's ID in the table. I want to be able to write one query where it updates if the player is already logged with the specific boss and inserts if he or she isn't.

**Research**: I did a lot of research online and people suggest the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but that only works if you either know your primary key or have a unique key, none of which I have or know.

**Tries**: I've tried

```
IF EXISTS (...) THEN UPDATE (...) ELSE INSERT(...)
```

and

```
UPDATE (...) IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO (...)
```

but they don't work. I get syntax errors.

If needed I can provide the errors thrown by the above tries. My current code for trying to update is this (but it throws a SQL syntax error):

Attempt 1:

```
UPDATE boss_kills 
  SET amount = amount + 1 
  WHERE characterid = ? AND mobid = ? 
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
  INSERT INTO boss_kills (characterid, mobid, amount) VALUES (?, ?, 1)
```

Attempt 2:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM boss_kills WHERE characterid = ? AND mobid = ?) 
THEN 
  INSERT INTO boss_kills VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, 1) 
ELSE 
  UPDATE boss_kills SET amount = amount + 1 WHERE characterid = ? AND mobid = ?
```

Comment: If you don't want to have it as unique key (it doesn't have to be the primary key, so you could just add a secondary index!), you cannot do it in one query. Do (in your client, e.g. php) a `select ... where ...` first. If it returns a row, `update`, else `insert`.

Comment: It seems like pair of columns `characterid, mobid` could make a unique index so I think you do have the unique key which you are not aware of.

Comment: @KamilG wait I can make 2 columns into a unique index? How would I do that?

Comment: @JonathanNguyen I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `(characterid, mobid)` could make a unique index constraint for your table, thus allowing you to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

**Use below script to create your table**

```
CREATE TABLE boss_kills (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  characterid int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  mobid int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  amount int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
  UNIQUE ( characterid, mobid )
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

*Note that I've removed backticks around your table and column names - they are not necessary.*

**Inserting a row**

```
INSERT INTO boss_kills (characterid, mobid, amount)
  VALUES (?, ?, 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + 1;
```